# Jenkins & Github - How to mask DB credentials?

Tags: java, github, jenkins, passwords, mask

We use github and jenkins for our project. Jenkins is pulling from the master (main branch) and then compile/package and deploy the project. The problem is our webapp project uses jdbc credentials and our github & jenkins are public. So is there a way to mask the username & password from both of them and keep jenkins deploying the project? Thanks

Comment: people often use environment variables to set information like that, but basically anything that comes from outside the code works. https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/blob/master/gradle/deploy.gradle#L95 for example

Comment: thanks it looks like its what im looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Mask Passwords Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin) to mask those credentials. After installation, your job configuration pages should have an checkbox option in the `Build Environment` section just like this:

[image]

You can click the **Add** button to add as many key-value pairs as you want and the values are masked with asterisks.

**To use these defined parameters**, you can use it like this: `${passwd}`

[image]

Please note, in your job console log, these parameters are also shown as asterisks, which is just as expected.